# YUI and jQuery: how to handle click events togheter

Tags: javascript, yui

this is my code, taken from YUi examples

```
YUI().use('anim', function(Y) {
    var anim = new Y.Anim({
        node: '#demo',
        duration: 0.5,
        easing: Y.Easing.elasticOut
    });

    var onClick = function(e) {
        anim.set('to', { xy: [e.pageX, e.pageY] });
        anim.run();
    };

    Y.one('#demo-stage').on('click', onClick);
});
```

the problem is I already have built functions in jQuery like

```
$("#demo-stage").bind('click',function(){
        // do something...
});
```

so how can Imerge them together?
Can I call from jquery bind the anim? how? Y.anim?
I also noticed that if I use

```
 Y.one('.multiples-demo-stage').on('click', onClick);
```

It applies the click method only on the first occurence of `multiples-demo-stage` div

why?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "merge them together"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, using both libraries leads to a lot of code transfer on the wire. You should avoid it if you can. In fact, I'm certain you can switch pretty easily from one library to the other, just look at the [JS Rosetta Stone](http://jsrosettastone.com/).

Regarding your specific question, to listen to the click event on multiple nodes you need to use `Y.all` instead of `Y.one`:

```
Y.all('.multiples-demo-stage').on('click', onClick);
```